# Counting html button clicks in JS front end and sending it to flask backend

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to track the number of times a button or a dropdown is clicked in my flask app and send it back to python backend so i can input into database. I keep getting null for my value i cant seem to figure it out.

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "POST">
        <button type="button" id = "numberclicks" name = "numberclicks" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
        <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks" name ="clicks" placeholder = 0 >{{clicks|safe}}</a></p>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        var clicks = 0;
        function onClick() {
           clicks += 1;
           document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks; 
           console.log(clicks)
        }   
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

import json

app = Flask(__name__)



# turn this into calss and import to record who is logged in to the session aka. user then take log data and make relationship to tables
# HOW MANY TIMES USER VISITED THE VISIT PAGE!!! 



@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signUpUser():
    if request.method == "POST":
        click = request.args.get('clicks',type = int)
        return json.dumps({'status':'OK','click':click})
    return render_template("new.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  console.log(clicks);
  fetch("/", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({clicks}),
  });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the flask back end to grab the click variable?

Comment: I don't know of flask, but on the client side there was no action that would POST the clicks so being flask or anything else wouldn't perform any action without first receiving the POST from the client.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XMLHttpRequest object to send the clicks count asychronously to the flask backend.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/", true);
xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        ...do whatever you want...
    }
}

const data = new FormData();
data.append("clicks", clicks);

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything to grab click variable in flask back end?

Comment: Yes, 'click = request.args.get('clicks',type = int)'. The data sent from the client is not going to be an int, it's going to be a string.

Comment: I can’t seem to get it to work can you show me a reproduceable example please

Comment: Okay. I'm not really into flask. But if it was Django, instead of returning a JSON response, you will render the template again but this time, sending the clicks variable to the template. E.g: "if request.method == "POST":
        click = request.args.get('clicks',type = int)
      #  return render_template("new.html", {'clicks' : clicks})
    return render_template("new.html")"